# Replace array of stings in array of files ignore space

Tags: php, replace, str-replace

I have multiple files where I need to do string replacemant. It works ok but it gets stuck on strings that have to much space or brake.

```
$replaceInFiles = array(

    'data.xml',
    'index.php',
    'layout.php'


);


$replaceStrings = array(
    'type="media" directory' => 'type="mymedia" directory',
    'bacjground' => 'background',
    '<user>user25</user>' => '',
    '<folder>fonts</folder>' => '',
    '<field name="layoutstyle">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                </field>' => ''
);



// replace in files
foreach ($replaceInFiles as $replaceFiles) {


    $readFile = file_get_contents($filesPath . '/' . $replaceFiles);

    $readFile = strtr($readFile, $replaceStrings);


    file_put_contents($filesPath . '/' . $replaceFiles, $readFile);

}
```

The last replacement string is not matched because of whistespace.
What would be the best approach?

Thank you!

**P.S. If you know a better way to do a replace of strings array in array of files please do share.**

Comment: Personally I'd go with regular expressions using preg_replace() for something tricky like this.

Comment: @Kisaro any examples?

Comment: For the last line, something like this might work:
  preg_replace('/<field(.*?)<\/field>/s', '', $readFile);

It takes the shortest occurence of "<field...</field>" and replaces it with an empty string.

Comment: works , i catch the file in question and do preg_replace after strtr